# Using channel with websocket

Tags: go, websocket

If I use a chan anywhere on main or func home, the application runs, but it doesn't really work. No errors thrown, however, it won't work.
If I remove the channels references, it goes back to working.
Either by using a chan in a struct or a global channel the application stops working.

In a `GET` request, it returns `h.Message` from `func home`
by adding any channel in the code, `GET` request wont return the message.

https://play.golang.org/p/-ZVcLhZRRRG

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    // _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type WMessage struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    ch      chan string
}

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}

var Chann chan string

func (h *WMessage) home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    h.Message = "hey this is the message from home"

    fmt.Fprintln(w, h.Message)
    fmt.Println(<-h.ch)
}

func main() {
    hom := &WMessage{}

    hom.ch = make(chan string)

    hom.ch <- "message sent"

    http.HandleFunc("/", hom.home)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("there was an error -> ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem statement. In what way does it not work? What do you see happening? What do you expect instead?

Comment: Pouching? I have no idea what that means. But I read your entire question. Your question decidedly does _not_ answer the question I asked you. Specifically: **What do you see happening? What do you expect instead?**

Comment: I expecting it to return to `h.Message` , for some reason, when a channel is used in there, it stops returning `h.Message` when a `GET` request is made to the server.
By removing any `channel` from the code, it then works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unbuffered channels are blocking in nature, i.e. writing to channel (`hom.ch <- "message sent"`) and reading from channel (`fmt.Println(<-h.ch)`) block the go-routine.

In your case, `http` server is not running because `hom.ch <- "message sent"` blocks the execution. That's why `GET` request is not working.

One simple solution can be to make it buffered channel instead.